# Pins for SIP Adapter

Tags: pins, adapter

Looking to make some SIP to DIP adapters and I'm trying to find some individual flat pins as per the below image - does anyone know where to get them or what they are called? An alternative is to use 2.54mm header strip (as used with Arduino for example), but these flat ones look a bit more flexible, which may be useful if the pins need to be bent over to enable fitting in tighter spaces. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: These doesn't looks reliable enough to fit into solderless breadboard. As it can cause pad to go off the board.

Comment: sacrifice a cheap 16 pin DIP IC .... solder the board to the pins and then cut off the sacrificial IC